# Converting ANTLR parse trees into string and then reverting it

Tags: antlr4, parse-tree

I am new to ANTLR, and I am digging into it for a project. My work would require me to generate a parse tree from a source code file, convert the parse tree into a string that holds all the information about the parse tree in a somewhat "human-readable" form. Parts of this string (representing the parse tree) will then be modified, and the modified string will have to be converted to a changed source code.

I have found out that the .toStringTree(tree) method can be used in ANTLR to print out the tree in LISP format. Is there a better way to represent the parse tree as a string that holds all information?

Can the string-parse-tree be reverted back to the original source code (in the same language) using ANTLR? If no, are there any tools for this?

Comment: For a transformation tool, the information outputted by ToStringTree() is not enough to reconstruct the source code. You will want to copy the runtime source and embellish it to do what you want. For example, you may want to provide a list of tokens with original source, and output handles for those in the parse tree. Intertoken information, the crux of a transformation tool, is not captured in ToStringTree(). There is no method in the runtime to reconstruct the source, but it is easy. I do a lot of tree rewritings in Antlrvsix, but it's all manual until I write a tree transformation system.

Comment: @kaby76 would converting the parse tree to a JSON structure hold sufficient information for the reversion?

Comment: A JSON serialization of the parse tree is insufficient, even if it contains every field of the Antlr data type, to reconstruct the source code character for character. It's not in the tree. If you don't want to skip reconstructing comments, spacing, etc, you will need to encode inter-token structures somewhere. As I said, that's the crux of all transformation tools. It's hard to deal with, e.g., moving around code because people make comments outside of syntactic structures. Anyway, it all depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the string-parse-tree be reverted back to the original source code (in the same language) using ANTLR?

That string does not contain the token types, just the matched text. In other words: you cannot create a parse tree from the output of the `ToStringTree`. Besides, many ANTLR grammars have lexer rules that skip certain input (white spaces and line breaks, for example), so converting a parse tree back to the original input source is not always possible.

> If no, are there any tools for this?

Without a doubt, I suggest you do a search on GitHub. But when you have the parse tree, it is trivial to create a custom tree structure and convert that to JSON.